# Android App String Arrays

Tags: android, xml, string

I would like to build an Android "Quotes" App. So basicly an app, in which i implement like 200 Strings(the Quotes of famous people), and every time i click on a button the next quote(String) appears on the textview. Of course these strings have to be saved anywhere, but i dont know how to create a string array. So any Ideas?

Thank you

Comment: I know, off topic, but: There are out so many quotes apps, please make something different! :>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make one arrays.xml file in res folder.

```
<string-array name="account_settings_email_retrieve_size_entries">
        <item>@string/account_setup_options1</item>
        <item>@string/account_setup_options2</item>
        <item>@string/account_setup_options3</item>
    </string-array>
```

Comment: ah ok, so you just have to set the string behind the "/"?

Comment: yup buddy... you have to set the string behing the / in strings.xml file in res folder  .... and then in java code you can access arrays R.arrays.xxjxjxjxj

Comment: You can actually specify the strings in line. <item>Quote goes here</item> works just as well.

Comment: And how cn i secify whch ofthe strings i want to use?... i have 200 strings set up

Comment: It would be good practice if you define your strings in string.xml as in future if you want to implement a regionalization independent code.